# Copy paste image into wordpress editor + import in media library?

Tags: wordpress

I am building a blog, and one of the category is based on images.
Yet I haven't found the solution to this simple question :

How do I import pictures in my media library via a simple copy paste in my post editor?

So far I've tested OnePress ImageElevator & ImagePaste but both of them simply paste an image from the website source and do not import it in my media library.

I would be eternally grateful if someone has the solution.

Thanks

Comment: would like to know as well...

Comment: What is the source you are copying from? Is it a file in the file system? Is it directly from an image editor? Or some other source?

Comment: It is from a website

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and free way I've found is to install OnePress Image Elevator and then use Firefox. Using the WP editor in Firefox, you can add images in the following three easy ways:

1) drag a file from desktop and drop it in the editor, 
2) clip an image to clipboard and paste it in the editor, and 
3) drag an image from an open Firefox browser and drop it in the editor

Also, you can view the step in this brief video
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BynQ_XEBrB4zWWRyWFVmSmZJcDg/view?usp=sharing